Why is the gain of the amplifier not considered in the frequency calculations? (Sedra and Smith 6th edition, Example 1.5)
In example 1.5 in Sedra & Smith 6th edition, the author's answer for item b) is 1 Mrad/s. To get this answer, the author considers the amplifier as a passive LP network and uses the time constant equation in table 1.2.

Copied from "Microelectronic Circuits", 6th Edition, Sedra & Smith, page 36.
My question is:
Why is the gain of the amplifier not considered in the frequency calculations? I mean, taking the magnitude of the transfer function, making it equal to unity and calculating for w, the result I obtained was 100 Mrad/s (due to 100 V/V gain of the amplifier).
What am I missing?

The unity-gain frequency (as mentioned by you) is NOT identical to the -3dB frequency (as mentioned in the book).


Why is the gain of the amplifier not considered in the frequency
calculations?

In simplest terms, it's because they are looking for a relative value when they write "3-dB-frequency" (which means \$-3\:\text{dB}\$.)
Say \$V_o=\kappa\cdot V_s\$ (with \$\kappa\propto \mu\$.)
\$V_o\$ depends on both \$V_i\$ and \$\kappa\$.
\$V_i\$ doesn't depend on \$\kappa\$.
Since \$V_o\propto V_i\$ when \$V_i\$ is \$-3\:\text{dB}\$ down, then \$V_o\$ will also be \$-3\:\text{dB}\$ down.
The \$-3\:\text{dB}\$ point doesn't depend on \$\kappa\$ (which depends on \$\mu\$.)

Makes sense and considering it as a relative quantity, the answer fits perfectly to what the author explains. Many thanks!!!

Just for future reference:
$$ |G(s)| = K \times 1/\sqrt{(1+(\omega \times C_i \times R_{eq})^2)} $$
$$ G(s)| / K = 1/\sqrt{(1+(\omega \times C_i \times R_{eq})^2)} $$
Considering
$$ G(s)|/K = 0,708 \space (-3 \space dB) $$
$$ R_{eq} = 16,67 \space k\Omega $$
$$ (C_i \times R_{eq})^2 = 1 \space p $$
Then
$$ 0,708 = 1/\sqrt{(1+(\omega \times C_i \times R_{eq})^2)} $$
$$ 0,5 = 1/(1+\omega^2 \times 1p) $$
$$ \omega^2 \times 1p = 1 $$
$$ \omega^2 = 1E12 $$
$$ \omega = 1 \space Mrad/s $$

For writing equations, please learn to use the math mark-up language supported on this site as in periblespsis ' answer . A quick reference to MathJax.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
